# Issue while trying to controlling LEGO Spike Prime motors using Visual Studio Code

Tags: python, error-handling, command-line, integration, robotics

I'm using the LEGO SPIKE Prime extension for Visual Studio Code from the GitHub blog (https://github.com/sanjayseshan/spikeprime-vscode) to develop a project. However, I'm encountering a "TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable" error. I'm seeking assistance in resolving this issue.

Project Description:
I'm working on a project that involves controlling the LEGO SPIKE Prime robot using the extension for Visual Studio Code. The extension provides various features and functionalities for interacting with the LEGO SPIKE Prime hardware.

Error Message:
When running the following command in the command line, I encounter the TypeError:

```
C:\Users\***\Desktop\lego\levov2>python C:\spiketools\spikejsonrpc.py -t COM17 upload "c:\Users\***\Desktop\lego\levov2\teste.py" 1
TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable
```

(Note: The username has been obscured for privacy reasons)

Issue:
The error occurs when executing the above command using the LEGO SPIKE Prime extension's "spikejsonrpc.py" script. It seems that the 'NoneType' error is related to an iterable object not being available during the execution.

Expected Behavior:
I expected the command to upload the "teste.py" file to the LEGO SPIKE Prime hub connected to the specified COM port without any errors.

Additional Information:
I have followed the installation steps provided in the GitHub blog for setting up the LEGO SPIKE Prime extension.
The LEGO SPIKE Prime hub is properly connected to COM17 and functional.
The "teste.py" file exists in the specified directory.
Request:
I would appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this TypeError when using the LEGO SPIKE Prime extension for Visual Studio Code. If there are any specific configurations or additional steps that need to be taken to ensure the proper functionality of the extension and the "spikejsonrpc.py" script, please let me know.

Thank you for your assistance!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.